# Is it possible to connect ms access through Rapid SQL

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am getting Login Failed error, when try to connect ms access database through Rapid SQL.
I created ODBC connection with user id and password and then tried.

I am wondering whether Rapid SQL supports ms Access

Appreciate your comments

Cheers

Shabar

Comment: First result in Google says it can http://www.theopensourcery.com/keepopen/2007/embarcadero-rapid-sql/

Comment: Thanks Remou, Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to connect to MS Access through `ODBC connection (MS Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb))`